# How to load 96 bits from memory into an XMM register?

Tags: assembly, intel, sse, sse2, sse4

Say I have a pointer to memory in `rsi`, and I would like to load the 12-byte
value pointed to into the low 96 bits of `xmm0`. I don't care what happens to
the high 32 bits. What's an efficient way to do this?

(Side question: the best I've come up with involves the `movlpd` "Move Low
Packed Double-Precision Floating-Point Value" instruction. Is there any way in
which this instructions is specific to floating-point values? I don't
understand what it's documented this way; surely it should work for integers
too.)

Answer (score 2):

If a 16byte load won't cross into another page and fault, then use `movups`.  The high 4 bytes will be whatever garbage is there in memory.  Causing a cache miss for the 4B you don't care about may be a problem, as might the cache-line split.

Otherwise use `movq` / `pinsrd` (SSE4.1), or some other way of doing two loads + a shuffle.  `movq` + `pinsrd` is going to be 3 fused-domain uops on Intel SnB-family CPUs, because `pinsrd` can't micro-fuse.  (And its ALU uop requires the shuffle port (p5)).

---

Another possibility: AVX `VMASKMOVPS xmm1, xmm2, m128`.

> Conditionally moves packed data elements from the second source operand into the corresponding data element
>   of the destination operand, depending on the mask bits associated with each data element (MSB of 1st src operand).
>
> ... Faults will not occur due to
>   referencing any memory location if the corresponding mask bit for that memory location is 0.

Intel Haswell: 3 fused-domain uops (one load and two shuffle (p5)).  4c latency, one per 2c throughput.

It's probably not very good compared, esp. if the surrounding code has to shuffle.

---

Your very-rarely-taken conditional branch that uses `movups` any time it's guaranteed not to fault is also 3 fused-domain uops on the fast-path, and one of them can run on port6 (not competing with vector ALUs at all).  The LEA isn't on the critical path either.

---

`movlpd` is safe to use on any data.  It will never fault or be slow with data that represents a floating point NaN, or anything like that.  You only have to worry about that with instructions that are listed in the insn ref manual with a non-empty "SIMD Floating-Point Exceptions" section.  e.g. `addps` can generate "Overflow, Underflow, Invalid, Precision, Denormal" exceptions, but `shufps` says "None".

Comment: Unfortunately I don't control the position or dimensions of the input, so I can't overread. `movq` and `pinsrd` is what I came up with too; thanks for confirming.

Comment: Thanks also for the note about `movlpd`. But my question is then: why is it documented as applying to floating-point values in particular?

Comment: @jacobsa: If you know there is readable memory *before* the 12B you want, you can load from `[addr-4]` and then shift (`psrldq`).  Or you could even mask the address to get a 16B-aligned pointer that covers some of the data you want (and still can't fault).

Comment: @jacobsa: IDK why there are so many different shuffles and stuff like `movhlps` for float vs. int.  I've never seen any rationale for the design decisions.  I always just assumed that Intel put in things that seemed like a good idea at the time, with some combination of MMX history with trying out other ideas when they designed SSE.  Of course, a future CPU design could have higher latency when forwarding the result of a `movlpd` load to an integer instruction.  That's clearly why they made `movupd` and `movdqu` when `movups` already existed.  Some designs (Nehalem) care for reg-reg moves...

Comment: Thanks very much, that makes sense.

Comment: @jacobsa: Have a look at [Agner Fog's guides](http://agner.org/optimize), if you haven't seen them.  He has good suggestions for combinations of instructions you might not think of for moving vector data around.  He also has very excellent microarchitecture writeups to understand the performance of different ways of implementing things.  Other links at the [x86 tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info)

Comment: @jacobsa: updated my answer with AVX `vmaskmov`, which I just noticed while looking for something else in the insn ref manual.

Answer (score 1):

Peter Cordes's answer helped by making me think of pages, and I wound up just checking whether there was any chance we'd fault:

```
 // We'd like to perform only a single load from memory, but there's no 96-bit
 // load instruction and it's not necessarily safe to load the full 128 bits
 // since this may read beyond the end of the buffer.
 //
 // However, observe that memory protection applies with granularity of at
 // most 4 KiB (the smallest page size). If the full 16 bytes lies within a
 // single 4 KiB page, then we're fine. If the 12 bytes we are to read
 // straddles a page boundary, then we're also fine (because the next four
 // bytes must lie in the second page, which we're already reading). The only
 // time we're not guaranteed to be okay to read 16 bytes is if the 12 bytes
 // we want to read lie near the end of one page, and some or all of the
 // following four bytes lie within the next page.
 //
 // In other words, the only time there's a risk is when the pointer mod 4096
 // is in the range [4081, 4085). This is <0.1% of addresses. Check for this
 // and handle it specially.
 //
 // We perform the check by adding 15 and then checking for the range [0, 3).
 lea rax, [rsi+15]
 test eax, 0xffc
 jz slow_read

 // Hooray, we can load from memory just once.
 movdqu xmm0, XMMWORD PTR [rsi]

done_reading:
 [...]

slow_read:
 movq xmm1, QWORD PTR [rsi]
 pinsrd xmm1, DWORD PTR [rsi+8], 2
 jmp done_reading
```

Comment: faster: `lea eax, [rsi+15]` / `test eax, 0xffc` / `jz`.  Since you're only interested in the low bytes, you don't need 64bit regs, saving bytes on REX prefixes.  I used eax because there's a special encoding of `test eax, imm32`.  You *could* modify this to use `slow_read` for cache-line splits too, but you'd probably lose much worse on branch-mispredicts than you'd gain.  You should test this against unconditionally using the `movq` / `pinsrd` to make sure it's better.  `lea` / `fused test-and-branch` / `movups` is 3 uops, same as `movq` / `pinsrd`, but shorter critical path.

Comment: Good old `lea`, how did I forget it? Thanks. My benchmark isn't sensitive enough to tell the difference here (or this isn't a bottleneck), but your patch is nicer. Done.

Comment: `lea EAX, [rsi+15]` saves another byte in the encoding.  The default address size is 64bit, but the default operand size is 32bit, even for LEA.  Also, it's weird that the `movdqu` loads to a different register than the `movq` / `pinsrd`.  (Also, you could save a byte with `movups`.  There's no downside to using FP loads/stores, and clang actually does this sometimes.  Do use the right insn type for the data for reg-reg moves, though, since some uarches care about that.)

Answer (score 0):

```
    movss xmm0, [rdx+8]         //; +8*8Bits = 64 Bits
    pshufd xmm0, xmm0, 0x00     //; spreading it in every part
    movlps xmm0, [rdx]          //; overwriting the lower with 64 Bits
```

It worked in my case with **Float**, not sure if it suits your.